# Login Authentication - Not able to connect to graphql from Nextjs with JWT Token using Apollo client

Tags: graphql, jwt, next.js, apollo-client

I am new to this technology. I am using Django as backend and Nextjs as frontend. I am trying to connect to graphql in backend with JWT using apollo client 3.3.8. When I try to connect I get graphql error as "Not Logged In".

```
import { ApolloClient, useQuery, HttpLink, ApolloLink, gql, createHttpLink,from } from '@apollo/client';
import {cache} from './cache'

import { useMemo } from "react";

export const typeDefs = gql`
  extend type Query {
    isLoggedIn: Boolean!
  }
`;


let apolloClient

function createIsomorphLink() {
  if (typeof window != 'undefined') {

    const { HttpLink } = require('@apollo/client/link/http')
    return new HttpLink({
      uri: 'http://localhost:8000/graphql/',
      headers: {
        authorization: localStorage.getItem('token') || null,

      }
    })
  }
}

function createApolloClient() {
  return new ApolloClient({
    ssrMode: typeof window === 'undefined',
    link: createIsomorphLink(),
    cache: cache,
  })
}

export function initializeApollo(initialState = null) {
  const _apolloClient = apolloClient ?? createApolloClient()

  // If your page has Next.js data fetching methods that use Apollo Client, the initial state
  // gets hydrated here
  if (initialState) {
    _apolloClient.cache.restore(initialState)
  }
  // For SSG and SSR always create a new Apollo Client
  if (typeof window === 'undefined') return _apolloClient
  // Create the Apollo Client once in the client
  if (!apolloClient) apolloClient = _apolloClient

  return _apolloClient
}

export function useApollo(initialState) {
  const store = useMemo(() => initializeApollo(initialState), [initialState])
  return store
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting the JWT from localStorage then I would recommend retrieving it before passing it in to the auth header. Perhaps create a globally reusable variable that reads the JWT from localStorage and that's its only job. Alternatively, try using `authLink` and concatenating `httpLink` to `authLink`. See the contents of my `apollo.ts` below:

```
import { useMemo } from 'react';
import {
    ApolloClient,
    InMemoryCache,
    NormalizedCacheObject,
    ApolloLink,
    HttpLink
} from '@apollo/client';
import fetch from 'isomorphic-unfetch';
import { IncomingHttpHeaders } from 'http';
import { setContext } from '@apollo/client/link/context';
import { onError } from '@apollo/client/link/error';
// import merge from 'deepmerge';
import { AppInitialProps, AppProps } from 'next/app';
// import { CookiesStatic } from 'js-cookie';
// import isEqual from 'lodash/isEqual';

export const APOLLO_STATE_PROP_NAME = '__APOLLO_STATE__';

let apolloClient:
    | ApolloClient<NormalizedCacheObject>
    | undefined;

const wpRefresh = process.env.WORDPRESS_AUTH_REFRESH_TOKEN!;
const oneEndpoint = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_ONEGRAPH_API_URL!;
function createApolloClient(
    headers: IncomingHttpHeaders | null = null
): ApolloClient<NormalizedCacheObject> {
    // const token = session?.jwt?.toString() ?? '';
    // const token =
    //  getAccessToken(options) ?? getAccessTokenAsCookie(options);

    const authLink: ApolloLink = setContext(
        (_, { ...headers }: Headers) => {
            let token: any;
            // you can getToken(token) etc. here
            if (!token) {
                return {};
            }
            return {
                headers: {
                    ...headers,
                    'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                    Auth: `Bearer ${wpRefresh}`,
                    'x-jwt-auth': token ? `Bearer ${token}` : ''
                },
                credentials: 'include',
                ...(typeof window !== undefined && { fetch })
            };
        }
    );
    const errorLink: ApolloLink = onError(
        ({ graphQLErrors, networkError }) => {
            if (graphQLErrors)
                graphQLErrors.forEach(({ message, locations, path }) =>
                    console.log(
                        `[GraphQL error]: Message: ${message}, Location: ${locations}, Path: ${path}`
                    )
                );
            if (networkError)
                console.log(
                    `[Network error]: ${networkError}. Backend is unreachable. Is it running?`
                );
        }
    );
    const httpLink = new HttpLink({
        uri: `${oneEndpoint}`
    });
    return new ApolloClient({
        ssrMode: typeof window === 'undefined',
        link: authLink.concat(httpLink) ?? errorLink,
        connectToDevTools: true,
        cache: new InMemoryCache({
            typePolicies: {
                Query: {
                    fields: {
                        // merge?: boolean | FieldMergeFunction<TExisting, TIncoming> | undefined;
                        wordpress: {
                            merge(existing, incoming, { mergeObjects }) {
                                // Invoking nested merge functions
                                return mergeObjects(existing, incoming);
                            }
                        },
                        google: {
                            merge(existing, incoming, { mergeObjects }) {
                                // Invoking nested merge functions
                                return mergeObjects(existing, incoming);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        })
    });
}
type InitialState = NormalizedCacheObject | any;

type IInitializeApollo = {
    headers?: null | NodeJS.Dict<string | string[]>;
    initialState?: InitialState | null;
};
export function initializeApollo(
    { headers, initialState }: IInitializeApollo = {
        headers: null,
        initialState: null
    }
) {
    // you can pass your JWT token in here 
    const _apolloClient =
        apolloClient ?? headers
            ? createApolloClient(headers)
            : createApolloClient();
    if (initialState) {
        // Get existing cache, loaded during client side data fetching
        const existingCache = _apolloClient.extract();
        // Merge the existing cache into data passed from getStaticProps/getServerSideProps
        const data = { ...existingCache, ...initialState };
        /* This is the deepmerge method -- below */
        // const data = merge(initialState, existingCache, {
        //  arrayMerge: (destinationArray, sourceArray) => [
        //      ...sourceArray,
        //      ...destinationArray.filter(d =>
        //          sourceArray.every(s => !isEqual(d, s))
        //      )
        //  ]
        // });
        // Restore the cache with the merged data
        _apolloClient.cache.restore(data);
    }
    // for SSG and SSR ALWAYS create a new Apollo Client
    if (typeof window === 'undefined') return _apolloClient;
    // Create the Apollo Client once in the client
    if (!apolloClient) apolloClient = _apolloClient;
    return _apolloClient;
}

export function addApolloState(
    client: ApolloClient<NormalizedCacheObject> | any,
    pageProps: (AppInitialProps | AppProps)['pageProps'] | any
) {
    if (pageProps?.props) {
        pageProps.props[
            APOLLO_STATE_PROP_NAME
        ] = client.cache.extract();
    }
    return pageProps;
}

export function useApollo(
    pageProps: (AppInitialProps | AppProps)['pageProps'] | any
) {
    const state = pageProps[APOLLO_STATE_PROP_NAME];
    const store = useMemo(
        () => initializeApollo({ initialState: state }),
        [state]
    );
    return store;
}
```